# How to build a REST API between two sites using DDEV?

Tags: drupal, ddev

I got two drupal sites running with DDEV.

First one is a Drupal 7 that populates data from database in several REST API endpoints.

The other one is a Drupal 9 that needs to consume the data from these endpoints.

I've found some posts like [Communication between two ddev projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51710272/communication-between-two-ddev-projects), but I can't get it working.

I'm quite noob with Docker & DDEV, so I will appreciate a step-by-step (or more accurate) guide about how configure both DDEV environments, so the Drupal 9 site can consume the REST API exposed by the Drupal 7 site.

The following are my DDEV config.yaml and `ddev describe` for both sites:

**Drupal 7 site:**

```
name: drupal7
type: drupal7
docroot: "www"
php_version: "5.6"
webserver_type: apache-fpm
router_http_port: "80"
router_https_port: "443"
xdebug_enabled: false
additional_hostnames: ['drupal7.local']
additional_fqdns: ['drupal7.local']
mariadb_version: "10.3"
mysql_version: ""
nfs_mount_enabled: true
mutagen_enabled: false
use_dns_when_possible: true
composer_version: "2"
web_environment: []
```

[image: dev describe for drupal 7 site]

**Drupal 9 site:**

```
name: drupal9
type: drupal9
docroot: web
php_version: "8.1"
webserver_type: apache-fpm
router_http_port: "80"
router_https_port: "443"
xdebug_enabled: false
additional_hostnames: ['drupal9.local']
additional_fqdns: ['drupal9.local']
database:
  type: mariadb
  version: "10.3"
nfs_mount_enabled: false
mutagen_enabled: false
use_dns_when_possible: true
composer_version: "2"
web_environment: []
nodejs_version: "16"
```

[image: ddev describe for drupal 9 site]

Additional info:

- DDEV 1.21.1
- Docker 20.10.17 (Docker Desktop 4.12.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two projects can easily communicate with each other, as described in the [FAQ](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/basics/faq/#can-different-projects-communicate-with-each-other)

Also see [Communication between two ddev projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51710272/communication-between-two-ddev-projects/53436970#53436970) and [Communicating between ddev projects via http/s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65834164/communicating-between-ddev-projects-via-http-s)

I hope those links will get you started. The bottom line is you can use either the full name of the web container (like `ddev-<projectname>-web` or the FQDN of the target site (like `https://someapi.ddev.site`) (second one requires minor configuration).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. It pointed me to the right direction. 

Finally I ended up with the setup explained in this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65834550/3523659 and it worked!